# if part of a phrase is found in a column using a for next loop, then output a numerical value to another cell in the same row

Tags: vba

Being very new to VBA, i've lurked on this site for ages and learnt a fair bit, but now have a question that I can't work out for myself.

my problem is as follows:
if part of a phrase (such as 'dogs are cool')is found in a column cell while running a for next loop, then output a numerical value to another cell in the same row - so in this case i'm searching column f and outputing on a true result to column j

i've been trying if then statements, but just can't seem to make it work - any thoguhts folks?

it's a 4,000 line document and it's a specific recurring phrase that i need to find, if it's there, it affects the value that the line is meant to calculate

Comment: `i've been trying if then statements` - show us, please, your attempts and what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do a simple search and provide the starting position. You can save the resulting vale wherever you like.

```
Function Find_String()
Dim strYourString       As String
Dim strSearchFor        As String
Dim iFound          As Integer
    strYourString = "Every day I think to myself: 'Dogs are cool'"
    strSearchFor = "dogs"

    iFound = InStr(1, strYourString, strSearchFor)
    If iFound > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found your words starting in position: " & iFound
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,
by plagiarizing Waynes solution, I've got what i needed to do do sorted out.

```
Sub findthenchangequantitycolumn()
Dim strYourString       As String
Dim strSearchFor        As String
Dim iFound          As Integer
For i = 9 To 3800
strYourString = Cells(i, 6).Value
strSearchFor = "TRAYS OF 20"

iFound = InStr(1, strYourString, strSearchFor)
If iFound > 0 Then Cells(i, 10).Value = 20
   iFound = 0
```

Next i
End Sub